# MongoDb - "join" or $in two collections

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have 2  collections:

```
> db.fellas.findOne()
{
    "_id" : 123
    "women" : [
        1,
        12,
        34
    ]
}

> db.women.findOne()
{ "_id" : 12, "busty" : 1 }
```

Some of the women belong to a certain fella, but some of them don't. In the case above, the woman does belong to the fella.

How do I find all women whose don't belong to any fella? I tried to do that using $unwind, but no luck. I mean, I'm unaware what I should do further.

Your ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with the agregation framework because it involves two diferent collections. You must take each women id and find it in women array of fellas collections.

Comment: It is for MongoDB M101 course. Isn't it? I've resolved the problem and you don't need to use the aggregation framework. It's easier than that.

Comment: No, unfortunately it is not possible to use the aggregation framework for querying two collections. According to the docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/ you run your aggregation query on ONE collection like: db.collName.aggregate(....)

Comment: m101 involves images and folders. In my case, it's fellas and women. So, it's not.

Comment: My main man, you opened my eyes. I'm going to use addToSet to solve that task. I even don't need to use women collection to get the sum.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function like the following one:

```
db.women.find().forEach(function(w){
  if( !db.fellas.findOne({ women:{$in:[w._id]} }) )
    printjson(w); 
)}
```

There is another way, namely mapreduce.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the aggregation framework does not support joins. This can be done (I have done it) with Hadoop, Apache Pig and the MongoDb+Hadoop connector. Apache Pig provides a high-level language that makes it pretty easy to join multiple data sources. It translates into map-reduce jobs that run in a Hadoop cluster.